# Why was their error [ 'int' object is not callable ] on the below code?

Tags: python

```
   P = 1000
   r = 10
   n = 2
   A = P(1 + r/100)**n
   print(A)
```

The error to the below code was 'int' object is not callable and based on my understanding, the error is if I have defined a variable and assigned an integer and I am using the same variable and using it as a function. I did correct my mistake but I want to know why there was an error in the first place

Comment: You are missing multiplication operand `*` after `P`. This is causing the error.

Comment: `P` is an integer. `P(...)` is the syntax for a function call. If you want multiplication, use the `*` operator.

Comment: Hey, I am aware the multiplication operand missing, but I wanted to know why this error came in first place

Comment: the error came because you misused the language. P() is a function call, P*(1+r/200)**n is a calculation.

Answer (score 1):

When you're calling `P(1 + r / 100)` it's like you are trying to call a function named `P` and you are trying to pass the argument `1 + r / 100`. What you are probably trying to do is to multiply by P, so you need to add an `*`

```
A = P * (1 + r / 100) **n
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, P is holding an int value. Thus, when you do `P(...)` it is being called i.e. it is calling `__call__` method of P. Given P is int it does not implement any such method. I think you are trying to perform a multiplication there so you should do `P * (...)`

Comment: Yes, Understood
Thanks